# URL Parameters not being read with SEO friendly filenames

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working in a WAMP localhost environment (WAMP 3.1.7X64bit) under Windows 10 Pro. As I am using SEO-friendly file names for my site, I went into the Apache `httpd.config` file and loaded the rewrite_module. My `htaccess` file has the following:

```
RewriteRule resource-files/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /resource-files.php?category=$1 [L]
```

And from my website I can click the rewritten link (like `/resource-files/financial-information`) which does appear correctly on the URL line.

However, my php code

```php
$get_category_title=($GET['category'] ? GetSQLValueString($GET['category'],"text") : "");
```

is returning an empty array (for `$GET`). I am not sure why.

If I open the `resource-files.php` and manually pass the parameter as `?category=financial-information` or any other parameter, the page displays correctly.

I promise this was working yesterday. I even restored from a backup and what was tested and approved yesterday is not working today.

I have the exact same issue with all of my other `RewriteRule` statements. None are "passing" the parameter. The URL is correct, the `$_GET` shows empty.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule resource-files/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /resource-files.php?category=$1 [L]
```

PHP code to read the url parameter:

```php
$get_category_title=($GET['category'] ? GetSQLValueString($GET['category'],"text") : "");
```

The `$_GET` should return financial-information as the variable being passed or any other value after the slash.

Comment: Investigate the rewrite log, and `print_r($_SERVER);`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `$GET` in your code but it should be `$_GET`.

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy here.  I did have $_GET.  Checking the apache error log I do see [core:alert] [pid 12036:tid 1256] [client ::1:51109] C:/wamp64/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewroteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Looks like a simple misspelling then? **RewroteRule** instead of **RewriteRule** ?

Comment: A misspelling in this forum but not in my code.  I still have the error

Comment: The error log has the Rewrote Rule error in the log, but my htaccess file never has this listed.  here is my code:  
$get_category_title=($_GET['category'] ? GetSQLValueString($_GET['category'],"text") : "none");
echo "got the category {$get_category_title}<br/>";
and my htacces is this:
RewriteRule ^resource-files/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /resource-files.php?category=$1 [L]